# Unit testing an array converted set

Tags: java

I have an array. I am required to convert it into set and then unit test. I successfully did the array to set conversation. But the unit test is not working. I am a new learner specially in unit testing. Please help.

```
public class ArrToSet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array = {"a","b","c"};
        System.out.println("Original Array: " + Arrays.toString(array));
    
        System.out.println("Array converted to Set: " + Arrays.stream(array).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    
    }
}
```

The unit test case I have written:

```
class ArrToSetTest {
    @Test
    void test() {

        ArrToSet ar = new ArrToSet();
    
         Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
            set.add("a");
            set.add("b");
            set.add("c");

        String actual[] = {"a","b","c"};
    
        assertEquals(set,actual);
   }
}
```

Comment: What are you testing for? What are you trying to assert?

Comment: If you're trying to assert that an array of strings equals a set, the assertion should always fail.

Comment: Try `assertThat(set, contains("a"));`. Don't pass that array of strings.

Comment: @Jason - I am testing for and want to assert if the array and the set is equal or not.

Comment: @Amitkumar- showing compiler error at contains when I copied and pasted this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't able to unit test a class that exposes its API through a `main` method without ugly hacks. If you refactor `ArrToSet` to expose meaningful API it'll be much easier to test:

```
public class ArrToSet {
  public Set<String> convert(String[] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array = {"a","b","c"};
    System.out.println("Original Array: " + Arrays.toString(array));
    ArrToSet arrToSet = ArrToSet();
    System.out.println("Array converted to Set: " + arrToSet.convert(array));
  }
}
```

Testing this is easy now:

```
@Test
void test() {
  ArrToSet ar = new ArrToSet();    
  Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
  set.add("a");
  set.add("b");
  set.add("c");

  String actual[] = {"a","b","c"};
    
  assertEquals(set, arrToSet.convert(actual));
}
```